# Generate high value IDs in appengine local dev server datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My entity in appengine datastore looks like

```
@Id 
private long playerId;
```

So in appengine whenever a new entity is created it gets assigned an ID more than 1000000. However whenever the code is run locally the ID starts from 1 and increments like 2, 3, 4, etc.

I have done certain assumption with  1000000 as the minimum player id , so my tests fails when IDs like 1, 3, 4, etc generated locally.

Is there any way to force the local server or test environment generate higher IDs similar to appengine environments.

Comment: you should not make any assumptions about ID's that will be generated, as the scheme could change without any warning.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Thanks, I am trying to change this assumption now. BTW nice talking to the great cricketer :)

Comment: got to do something now I'm retired :P heh, not really :)

Answer (score 1):

To specify the automatic ID policy, set the `datastore.auto_id_allocation_policy` system property to either `sequential` or `scattered`.

- **sequential:** IDs are assigned from the sequence of consecutive integers.
- **scattered:** IDs are assigned from a non-repeating sequence of approximately uniformly distributed integers.

You can do this as follows:

```
-Ddatastore.auto_id_allocation_policy=scattered
```

To set this system property through a flag passed to the dev_appserver macro:

```
dev_appserver --jvm_flag=-Ddatastore.auto_id_allocation_policy=scattered
```

You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Using_the_Datastore).